# Javafx RotateTransition rendering smooth

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I’m making some trials with JavaFX RotateTransition, applying a simple model found on a jfx itself documentation file:

```
    rotateTransition = RotateTransitionBuilder.create()
            .node(elements)
            .duration(Duration.seconds(4))
            .fromAngle(0)
            .toAngle(720)
            .cycleCount(3)
            .autoReverse(true)
            .build();
```

Above, `elements` is a `Group` of bare `Arc` primitives.

When this group has a limited number of nodes, say 20, the animation goes smooth but when I increase the number of nodes to 500 (nested actually, Group of Group) the animation still works but does not result any more fluid.

The question is: does this nodes limit can be considered too much for this task? How to speed up the rendering?

I have found the thread below that in a similar context asserts that could be a matter of using the right Animation class, but I’m not sure that the proposed `AnimationTimer` does apply well to a rotation.

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-June/008104.html

I have also tried to use `setCache(true)` to every node with no visible improvements.

Thank you!

Edit: Arc generation. No strange things but a binder and a EventHandler.

```
Arc arc = new Arc();
arc.centerXProperty().bind(plotRadiusBinding);
arc.centerYProperty().bind(plotRadiusBinding);
arc.radiusXProperty().bind(plotRadiusBinding);
arc.radiusYProperty().bind(plotRadiusBinding);        
arc.setStartAngle(startAngle * 180 / PI);
arc.setLength(radiansLength * 180 / PI);

arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
arc.setStroke(defaultArcColor);
arc.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
arc.setFill(null);

arc.setOnMouseClicked(arcEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when moving images around when I used KeyFrames ([KeyFrames](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/KeyFrameandTimelinebasedanimation.htm))
I could improve it by using

I had success with implementing the stuff by myself:

```
Animation animation = new Transition() {

  {
    setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
  }

   @Override
   protected void interpolate(double frac) {
     // your rotation code here
   }
}
```

If you could provide your arc generation source code it might be helpful.

Comment: I tried your solution with no success. I used: `class MyTransition extends Transition {
    
    {
        setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(100000));
    }
    
    private double start = 0;
    private double delta = .1;
    private Node cachedNode;

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        start += delta;
        cachedNode.setRotate(start);
        
    }

    public void setNode(Node n){
        cachedNode = n;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

for me this works flawlessly for 500 arcs:

```
package application;

import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = new Pane();

            Group group = new Group();

            Random rand = new Random();


            for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
                Arc c = new Arc(200 + rand.nextInt(400), 200 + rand.nextInt(400), 10, 10, 0, 360);

                group.getChildren().add(c);
            }

            root.getChildren().add(group);

            RotateTransition  rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(5000), group);
            rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
            rotateTransition.setToAngle(720);
            rotateTransition.setCycleCount(3);
            rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

            rotateTransition.play();



            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

if this is still to laggy and you only want to draw arcs you could directly invoke the graphics-context of a canvas.